# How can I use for loops to make this simpler?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like this:

```
|File name|Sample|Thickness|
|D210215-3-2-1 cell100_00_mes.txt|D210215-3-2-1|100|
|D210215-3-2-4 cell500_00_mes.txt|D210215-3-2-4 |100|
|D210215-3-2-2 cell200_00_mes.txt|D210215-3-2-2 |125|
|D210215-3-3-1 cell500_00_mes.txt|D210215-3-3-1 |125|
|D210215-3-2-3 cell600_00_mes.txt|D210215-3-2-3 |150|
|D210215-3-3-2 cell400_00_mes.txt|D210215-3-3-2 |150|
|D210215-3-4-1 cell100_00_mes.txt|D210215-3-4-1 |150|
|etc...|etc...|etc...|
```

I then assign each File name to a variable:

```
searchdf0 = df.iloc[0]["File_name"]
searchdf1 = df.iloc[1]["File_name"]
searchdf2 = df.iloc[2]["File_name"]
searchdf3 = df.iloc[3]["File_name"]
searchdf4 = df.iloc[4]["File_name"]
searchdf5 = df.iloc[5]["File_name"]
searchdf6 = df.iloc[6]["File_name"]
etc...
```

I then use each variable to open a file:

```
xx0 = pd.read_csv(searchdf0, sep=None, engine='python', index_col=None, header=None)
xx1 = pd.read_csv(searchdf1, sep=None, engine='python', index_col=None, header=None)
xx2 = pd.read_csv(searchdf2, sep=None, engine='python', index_col=None, header=None)
xx3 = pd.read_csv(searchdf3, sep=None, engine='python', index_col=None, header=None)
xx4 = pd.read_csv(searchdf4, sep=None, engine='python', index_col=None, header=None)
xx5 = pd.read_csv(searchdf5, sep=None, engine='python', index_col=None, header=None)
xx6 = pd.read_csv(searchdf6, sep=None, engine='python', index_col=None, header=None)
etc...
```

I'm wondering how I can simplify this with a for loop? Or any other recommendations would be welcome!

Of course, I have the issue that every time my d f varies in length, I have to edit the code (searchdf7... searchdf8...  etc.)

Thanks,
Calum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the entire thing in a single list comprehension:

```
xx = [
    pd.read_csv(
        i["File_name"], 
        sep=None, 
        engine='python', 
        index_col=None, 
        header=None
    ) 
    for i in df.iloc
]
```

Now your `xx0`, `xx1`, etc values are stored as `xx[0]`, `xx[1]`, etc.  You don't need to update this code when new values are added to the dataframe, since it automatically loops over everything in `df.iloc` and makes a corresponding entry in the `xx` list for each.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, will save me a lot of time! Thanks